# My Rust project is broken all of the sudden

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

So I made some changes to my code and tried to compile it on my work computer. I got the following errors relative to ntapi package:

```
    error[E0793]: reference to packed field is unaligned
    --> C:\Users\u\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1eccb9ec823\ntapi-0.3.6\src\ntexapi.rs:2785:52
     |
2785 |         *tick_count.QuadPart_mut() = read_volatile(&(*USER_SHARED_DATA).u.TickCountQuad);
     |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: fields of packed structs are not properly aligned, and creating a misaligned reference is undefined behavior (even if that reference is never dereferenced)
     = help: copy the field contents to a local variable, or replace the reference with a raw pointer and use `read_unaligned`/`write_unaligned` (loads and stores via `*p` must be properly aligned even when using raw pointers)

error[E0793]: reference to packed field is unaligned
    --> C:\Users\u\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc9ec823\ntapi-0.3.6\src\ntexapi.rs:2809:25
     |
2809 |         ((read_volatile(&(*USER_SHARED_DATA).u.TickCountQuad)
     |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: fields of packed structs are not properly aligned, and creating a misaligned reference is undefined behavior (even if that reference is never dereferenced)
     = help: copy the field contents to a local variable, or replace the reference with a raw pointer and use `read_unaligned`/`write_unaligned` (loads and stores via `*p` must be properly aligned even when using raw pointers)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0793`.
error: could not compile `ntapi` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Some hours of trying to figure out the problem followed. As described in [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1826485) thread I tried to force update ntapi but I didn't manage to do it. When I got home I commited the changes and pulled on my home PC. Turned out it compile no problem on my home PC. I'm confused. Anyone knows what is happening here?

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "caravel"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
futures = "0.3"
anyhow = "1.0.32"
clap = "3.0.0-beta.5"
structopt = "0.3.16"
shell-words = "1.0.0"
futures-util = "0.3.17"
env_logger = "0.9"
log = "0.4"


[target.'cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))'.dependencies]
tokio-socketcan = "0.3.0"
```

cargo tree output:

```
caravel v0.1.0 ()
├── anyhow v1.0.44
├── clap v3.0.0-beta.5
│   ├── atty v0.2.14
│   │   └── winapi v0.3.9
│   ├── bitflags v1.3.2
│   ├── clap_derive v3.0.0-beta.5 (proc-macro)
│   │   ├── heck v0.3.3
│   │   │   └── unicode-segmentation v1.8.0
│   │   ├── proc-macro-error v1.0.4
│   │   │   ├── proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4 (proc-macro)
│   │   │   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.29
│   │   │   │   │   └── unicode-xid v0.2.2
│   │   │   │   └── quote v1.0.10
│   │   │   │       └── proc-macro2 v1.0.29 (*)
│   │   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   │   └── version_check v0.9.3
│   │   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.29 (*)
│   │   │   ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
│   │   │   └── syn v1.0.80
│   │   │       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.29 (*)
│   │   │       ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
│   │   │       └── unicode-xid v0.2.2
│   │   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   │   └── version_check v0.9.3
│   │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.29 (*)
│   │   ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
│   │   └── syn v1.0.80 (*)
│   ├── indexmap v1.7.0
│   │   └── hashbrown v0.11.2
│   │   [build-dependencies]
│   │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   ├── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   ├── os_str_bytes v4.2.0
│   │   └── memchr v2.4.1
│   ├── strsim v0.10.0
│   ├── termcolor v1.1.2
│   │   └── winapi-util v0.1.5
│   │       └── winapi v0.3.9
│   ├── textwrap v0.14.2
│   │   └── unicode-width v0.1.9
│   └── unicase v2.6.0
│       [build-dependencies]
│       └── version_check v0.9.3
├── env_logger v0.9.0
│   ├── atty v0.2.14 (*)
│   ├── humantime v2.1.0
│   ├── log v0.4.14
│   │   └── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   ├── regex v1.5.4
│   │   ├── aho-corasick v0.7.18
│   │   │   └── memchr v2.4.1
│   │   ├── memchr v2.4.1
│   │   └── regex-syntax v0.6.25
│   └── termcolor v1.1.2 (*)
├── futures v0.3.17
│   ├── futures-channel v0.3.17
│   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.17
│   │   └── futures-sink v0.3.17
│   ├── futures-core v0.3.17
│   ├── futures-executor v0.3.17
│   │   ├── futures-core v0.3.17
│   │   ├── futures-task v0.3.17
│   │   └── futures-util v0.3.17
│   │       ├── futures-channel v0.3.17 (*)
│   │       ├── futures-core v0.3.17
│   │       ├── futures-io v0.3.17
│   │       ├── futures-macro v0.3.17 (proc-macro)
│   │       │   ├── proc-macro-hack v0.5.19 (proc-macro)
│   │       │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.29 (*)
│   │       │   ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
│   │       │   └── syn v1.0.80 (*)
│   │       │   [build-dependencies]
│   │       │   └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   │       ├── futures-sink v0.3.17
│   │       ├── futures-task v0.3.17
│   │       ├── memchr v2.4.1
│   │       ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.7
│   │       ├── pin-utils v0.1.0
│   │       ├── proc-macro-hack v0.5.19 (proc-macro)
│   │       ├── proc-macro-nested v0.1.7
│   │       └── slab v0.4.5
│   │       [build-dependencies]
│   │       └── autocfg v1.0.1
│   ├── futures-io v0.3.17
│   ├── futures-sink v0.3.17
│   ├── futures-task v0.3.17
│   └── futures-util v0.3.17 (*)
├── futures-util v0.3.17 (*)
├── log v0.4.14 (*)
├── shell-words v1.0.0
├── structopt v0.3.25
│   ├── clap v2.33.3
│   │   ├── atty v0.2.14 (*)
│   │   ├── bitflags v1.3.2
│   │   ├── strsim v0.8.0
│   │   ├── textwrap v0.11.0
│   │   │   └── unicode-width v0.1.9
│   │   ├── unicode-width v0.1.9
│   │   └── vec_map v0.8.2
│   ├── lazy_static v1.4.0
│   └── structopt-derive v0.4.18 (proc-macro)
│       ├── heck v0.3.3 (*)
│       ├── proc-macro-error v1.0.4 (*)
│       ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.29 (*)
│       ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
│       └── syn v1.0.80 (*)
└── tokio v1.12.0
    ├── bytes v1.1.0
    ├── memchr v2.4.1
    ├── mio v0.7.13
    │   ├── log v0.4.14 (*)
    │   ├── miow v0.3.7
    │   │   └── winapi v0.3.9
    │   ├── ntapi v0.3.6
    │   │   └── winapi v0.3.9
    │   └── winapi v0.3.9
    ├── num_cpus v1.13.0
    │   └── libc v0.2.103
    ├── once_cell v1.8.0
    ├── parking_lot v0.11.2
    │   ├── instant v0.1.11
    │   │   └── cfg-if v1.0.0
    │   ├── lock_api v0.4.5
    │   │   └── scopeguard v1.1.0
    │   └── parking_lot_core v0.8.5
    │       ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
    │       ├── instant v0.1.11 (*)
    │       ├── smallvec v1.7.0
    │       └── winapi v0.3.9
    ├── pin-project-lite v0.2.7
    ├── tokio-macros v1.4.1 (proc-macro)
    │   ├── proc-macro2 v1.0.29 (*)
    │   ├── quote v1.0.10 (*)
    │   └── syn v1.0.80 (*)
    └── winapi v0.3.9
    [build-dependencies]
    └── autocfg v1.0.1
```

cargo -V:

```
cargo 1.69.0 (6e9a83356 2023-04-12)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also, please put a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code in your post.

Comment: Also add your `Cargo.toml` and the output of `cargo -V`.

Comment: Please post the output of `cargo tree`.

Comment: Likely your Rust version on home is outdated. Put here also the result of `cargo -V` on home and work.

Comment: Added everything cargo tree and cargo -V @ChayimFriedman

Comment: Is this `cargo -V` on home or work?

Comment: Right now I can't check version at home though

Comment: It's the one at work

Comment: Well, it shows that on work it's not outdated, but it doesn't prove it is on home. I can guess that fairly surely, however.

Comment: Try specifying `tokio`'s version as `"1.28.0"` instead of `"1"`.

Comment: It worked. May I ask what brought you to the suggestion of specifying the version to 1.28.0? Specifying it as "1" should make cargo use the latest 1.x.x version right?

Comment: @RodrigoCastro You're right, unless there is a version conflict. I don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: Weirder is it working on work computer and not at home. Wouldn't a version conflict be present on the same repo at home no matter rust's version?

Comment: @RodrigoCastro it has happended to me in the past that synchronizing between two computers broke Cargo's bookkeeping of which versions of libraries are currently already compiled, and where to find them, and resulted in various ugly errors during the compilation. What worked for me was `cargo clean`, forcing Cargo to redo everything.

Comment: I tried cargo clean, but ended up making no difference, I even tried to reinstall rust's toolchain altogether

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason (I don't know why) Cargo picked an older version of `tokio` that used (indirectly) an older version of `ntapi` that used [a construct](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82523) that was always UB, but because it was allowed in the past, it used to only trigger a soft future-incompatibility warning. But [as of Rust 1.69.0 it became a hard error](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/102513/), and therefore at work it didn't compile. It is likely that your version at home is lower, so it worked there.

Force Cargo to use new `tokio` by setting its version to `"1.28.0"` (the newest version), and it should work.

Comment: Cargo is free to choose any version `>=1.0.0 <2.0.0` if it's specified as just `version = "1"`, right? It might have figured out that if it used `tokio@1.12` it can share more dependencies with other crates (possibly all the proc macro ones, they all use the same versions of `quote`, `syn`, `proc-macro2`, etc.).

Comment: @isaactfa I don't believe it is working this way, I think it only considers the version of this crate. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Rust n00b here. *...that used a construct that was always UB* -> what does UB mean in this context?

Comment: @PaulH [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still confused,

Just run the following command instead of the one provided in the [official docs](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/installation#anchor),

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor avm --force
```

The only difference is having the `--locked` flag removed. The reason is well answered by other participants and the GitHub issue [#2567](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2567)

The issue can be traced to installation errors and hence the highlight on proper installation of avm.

Make sure to have all the prerequisites fulfilled like having rust by following installations [here](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install), Solana-cli from [here](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools), and lastly install yarn with the following command for Windows,

```
npm install --global yarn
```

This seemed to work for me on my Windows 11 machine, without using WSL.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue when migrating to a new dev machine. The fix for me was in my *Cargo.toml* file i have to update

```
tokio = "1.17.0"
```

to

```
tokio = "1.28.0"
```

then running rust-analyser or cargo run the project built sucessfully